# Web-камера в Java

Tags: web-camera, java

Ребята, есть вопрос. Как научить java работать с веб-камерой? что нужно для такой задачки, как вывод картинки с нее на обычный фрейм? и можно ли потом это изображение с помощью сокета передавать куда-нибудь(например на другой компьютер по локалке)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека - [JMyron](http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/)

Пример использования:

```
myron = new JMyron();
myron.start(imgw, imgh);
myron.update();
int[] img = myron.image();
```

Comment: А простенький примерчик рабочего кода не дадите?=)

Comment: Честно говоря, уверен, что эта штука не будет работать. Всё что я видел, связанное с веб-камерами, либо не работает вообще, либо выдаёт крэш в нативной части и тянет за собой виртуальную машину. Либо просто не имеет сборок для x86_64

Comment: OpenCV прекрасно работает для x86_64